# Laravel получение pivot данных при Many to many связи

Tags: laravel

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так. В проекте существуют следующие таблицы:

```
excursion_dates ->
    id
    created_at
    updated_at

ticket_types ->
    id
    title

excursion_date_ticket_type ->
    id
    excursion_date_id
    ticket_type_id
    count
    price
```

Необходимо связать первые две таблицы, чтобы у `ExcursionDate` было много `TicketType`. Добавление новых я смог сделать, но получение данных из существующих не получается. Не работает этот код:

```
ExcursionDate::first()->ticketTypes->first()->title
```

Ошибка:

```
Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'site.excursion_date_ticket_types' doesn't exist (SQL: select `excursion_date_ticket_types`.*, `excursion_date_ticket_type`.`excursion_date_id` as `pivot_excursion_date_id`, `excursion_date_ticket_type`.`ticket_type_id` as `pivot_ticket_type_id`, `excursion_date_ticket_type`.`price` as `pivot_price`, `excursion_date_ticket_type`.`count` as `pivot_count` from `excursion_date_ticket_types` inner join `excursion_date_ticket_type` on `excursion_date_ticket_types`.`id` = `excursion_date_ticket_type`.`ticket_type_id` where `excursion_date_ticket_type`.`excursion_date_id` = 1)
```

Где я мог ошибиться?

Models\ExcursionDateTicketType

```
class ExcursionDateTicketType extends Model
{

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
  protected $fillable = [
    'ticket_type_id', 'excursion_date_id', 'price', 'count'
  ];

  protected $table = 'excursion_date_ticket_type';

/**
   * Many to Many relation
   *
   * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\belongsToMany
   */
 public function ticketType()
 {
    return $this->belongsToMany(TicketType::class, 'excursion_date_ticket_types', 'ticket_type_id', 'excursion_date_id');
  }

  /**
   * One to Many relation
   *
   * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
   */
  public function excursionDate()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany(excursionDate::class, 'excursion_date_ticket_types', 'excursion_date_id', 'ticket_type_id');
  }

}
```

Models\ExcursionDate

```
class ExcursionDate extends Model
{

  /**
   * The attributes that are mass assignable.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $fillable = [
    'tour_date_start', 'tour_date_finish', 'sell_date_start', 'sell_date_finish',
    'booking_date_start', 'booking_date_finish', 'address', 'warranty', 'special',
    'discount', 'hot', 'payspot', 'booking'
 ];

  protected $table = 'excursion_dates';

  /**
   * Many to Many relation
   *
   * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\belongsToMany
   */
  public function ticketTypes()
  {
      return $this->belongsToMany(ExcursionDateTicketType::class, 'excursion_date_ticket_type', 'excursion_date_id', 'ticket_type_id')->withPivot('price', 'count');
  }

}
```

Models\TicketType

```
class TicketType extends Model
{

  /**
   * The attributes that are mass assignable.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $fillable = [
    'title', 'description'
  ];

  protected $table = 'ticket_types';

  /**
   * Many to Many relation
   *
   * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\belongsToMany
   */
  public function excursions()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany(ExcursionDate::class)->withPivot('price', 'count');
  }

}
```

UPD:

После явного указания $table во всех моделях ошибка поменялась на:

```
Not unique table/alias: 'excursion_date_ticket_type' (SQL: select `excursion_date_ticket_type`.*, `excursion_date_ticket_type`.`excursion_date_id` as `pivot_excursion_date_id`, `excursion_date_ticket_type`.`ticket_type_id` as `pivot_ticket_type_id`, `excursion_date_ticket_type`.`price` as `pivot_price`, `excursion_date_ticket_type`.`count` as `pivot_count` from `excursion_date_ticket_type` inner join `excursion_date_ticket_type` on `excursion_date_ticket_type`.`id` = `excursion_date_ticket_type`.`ticket_type_id` where `excursion_date_ticket_type`.`excursion_date_id` = 1)
```

Comment: Можешь представить обе модели?

Comment: Или если ты используешь свою `pivot` модель, то представь еще и ее. Основную проблему я указал в ответе

Comment: @МаксимК Добавил модели

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что ты пытаешься связать модель `ExcursionDate` с моделью `ExcursionDateTicketType`. Если бы ты связывал с моделью `TicketType`, то проблем бы не было.

Но если у тебя модель `TicketType` (исходя из названия таблицы `ticket_types`) называется `ExcursionDateTicketType`, то тебе надо либо переименовать ее в `TicketType`, либо явно прописать свойство `protected $table = 'ticket_types';`

upd: 
В модели `ExcursionDate` замени

```
/**
 * Many to Many relation
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\belongsToMany
 */
public function ticketTypes()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany(TicketType::class, 'excursion_date_ticket_type', 'excursion_date_id', 'ticket_type_id')->withPivot('price', 'count');
}
```

Плюс можешь не использовать модель `ExcursionDateTicketType`, она тебе в принципе скорее всего не нужна. Если ты считаешь, что нужна, пересмотри код еще раз. Дополнительные данные в `pivot` таблице (`count`, `price`) можно [добавлять/обновлять из методов отношений](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships)

Comment: Указание table во всех моделях частично помогло, но появилась другая ошибка. ExcursionDateTicketType мне необходим из-за возможности указания price и count для конкретной ExcursionDate с TicketType.